# Mapping multiple different JSON sources into one viewmodel with Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to map multiple (different) JSON sources into one viewModel, but I can't seem to get it working.

**I created a viewModel:**

```
    var viewModel;
```

**I created different mapping options like below:**

```
    var mappingPerformedActions = {
        'PerformedActions': {
            key: function(data) {
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.Id);
            }
        }
    };

    var mappingEntities = {
        'Entities': {
            key: function(data) {
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.Id);
            }
        }
    };
```

**Then I build my get function:**

```
    get = function() {

        $.getJSON("localhost/urlWhichWorksWithSingleMapping", function(getdata) {
            viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(getdata, mappingEntities );
        });

        $.getJSON("localhost/anotherUrlWhichWorksWithSingleMapping", function(getdata) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(getdata, mappingPerformedActions, viewModel);
        });

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    };

get();
```

**Then I try to loop trough Entities**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: BiztalkEntities">
    <li><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></li>
</ul>
```

**This works with single sources**

Note that all this works when I have just one source, so there are no mistakes in URLS or something. I have looked over stack overflow, but can't seem to find an example that fits my needs, I hope you could tell me what I am doing wrong here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your viewModel with two different properties and map to those. Otherwise you need to merge data into single array:

var viewModel = { PerformedActions: [], Entities: [] };

Then assign received data:

```
   $.getJSON("localhost/urlWhichWorksWithSingleMapping", function(getdata) {
        viewModel.PerformedActions = ko.mapping.fromJS(getdata, mappingEntities );
    });


    $.getJSON("localhost/anotherUrlWhichWorksWithSingleMapping", function(getdata) {
        viewModel.Entities = ko.mapping.fromJS(getdata, mappingPerformedActions);
    });
```

This is asynchronous, so at the time of binding you still don't have data. This is the best I can come up, it is not very clear where is the issue. Check console for errors, this will help you understand where the issue is.